# Linux to QNX USB driver convert

Tags: linux, usb, linux-device-driver, libusb, qnx

I've just started using QNX. I'm trying to write a USB3 vision driver under QNX by adapting a code found on GitHub:
https://github.com/ni/usb3vision/tree/master

and I wanted to know how to replace the `usb_bulk_msg()` function by the functions of the QNX libusbdi but I can't figure out how to do it.

Most of the functions are identical, but I can't figure out how to replace `usb_bulk_msg()`.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I only have access to `libusbdi` documentation for QNX 6.5 and prior.  At that time, QNX libusbdi did not supply synchronous messaging functions, only an asynchronous completion callback interface via `usbd_io`.  You will need to write your own shim function.

`usb_bulk_msg` itself is actually implemented using an underlying asynchronous USB API very similar to libusbdi; you can use the kernel source code there as a guide on how to implement it.  On QNX, `struct completion` could be implemented with a condvar.  Note that you'll also need to track outstanding requests so as to manage cleanup in the device removal callback.